# What does create-react-app use the TypeScript compiler for?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

With the new `--typescript` option, Create React App generates a dependency on the `typescript` compiler (among several other changes). However it uses `@babel/preset-typescript` for compiling TypeScript. So what does it use the TypeScript compiler for? Also, what is the `tsconfig.js` file used for?

Comment: Some people may choose to write their react application using TypeScript(https://www.typescriptlang.org/), which is essentially a superset of JavaScript. However, it still needs to be transpiled into JavaScript before running to application. `tsconfig` the settings which specifies the root files, and other options required to compile the application.

Comment: @wentjun, I just clarified my question. I am already using TypeScript with my React project, however I was curious where CRA uses the the typescript compiler vs the Babel TypeScript plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@babel/plugin-transform-typescript` that is used by `@babel/preset-typescript` doesn't make type checking, it just strips out type information which is much faster. For type checking you need to install and set up TypeScript.

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript/